# JetBrains Rider debugging on Mac

Tags: vb.net, debugging, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am just trying to get started with Rider to learn VB on a Mac. The code I wrote is

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        System.Console.WriteLine("Log text")
    End Sub
End Module
```

then I get an error

> Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(73, 5): [MSB3082] Task failed
>   because "vbc.exe" was not found.

Rider is a fresh install, I have researched but everywhere talks about windows not Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current mono(5.4.1.7) does not contain vbc.exe. Request for this problem(https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/6127) already fixed and merged into master. I think it the problem will be fixed when mono shipped the new version. Right now you can use .NET Core VB project to learn VB. Build and debug will work in Rider.